# org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: while saving data in one to one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, dao, model-driven

I am trying to save data to database (into two tables, with `One-To-One` mapping).

I am using Hibernate, Struts2 and a MySQL database.

While saving data it is showing the following exception:

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

**Atom.hbm.xml**

```xml
<class name="hibernetMappings.Atom" table="atom" catalog="xrcwrn_sms">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="200" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="type" type="string">
        <column name="type" length="100" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="page" class="hibernetMappings.Pages" cascade="save-update">
    </one-to-one>
</class>
```

**pages.hbm.xml**

```xml
<class name="hibernetMappings.Pages" table="pages" catalog="xrcwrn_sms">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">atom</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="atom" class="hibernetMappings.Atom"
                       constrained="true">
    </one-to-one>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="100" />
    </property>
</class>
```

**Atom.java**

```
public class Atom implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Pages page;

   //getters setters and constructor
}
```

In **Pages.java**

```
public class Pages  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private int id;
     private Atom atom;
     private String name;
     //getter setter and constructor
}
```

In **JSP**

```jsp
<s:form action="createPage" method="post">
    Display Type <s:textfield name="atom.type" />
    Display Name <s:textfield name="atom.name" />
    Name of page <s:textfield name="atom.page.name" />

    <s:submit value="Create" />
</s:form>
```

In **Action**

```
public class pageAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Atom> {

    Atom atom = new Atom();

    public String newPage() {
        System.out.println("In action");
        PageDAO pd=new PageDAO();
        pd.insertPage(getAtom());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Atom getAtom() {
        return atom;
    }

    public void setAtom(Atom atom) {
        this.atom = atom;
    }

    @Override
    public Atom getModel() {    
        return atom;    
    }
}
```

In **DAO**

```
public class PageDAO {
     public void insertPage(Atom atom) {

            System.out.println("In Dao");
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Pages page = new Pages();
            page.setAtom(atom);
            session.save(atom);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Done");
     }
}
```

Full StackTrace:

```
SEVERE:   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [hibernetMappings.Atom]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2853)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at page.PageDAO.insertPage(PageDAO.java:31)
    at page.pageAction.newPage(pageAction.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.service
SEVERE:   s.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2325)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:56)
    ... 98 more
```

Comment: In which dialect it's talking?

Comment: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: Post a stacktrace, so you can see where exception is instantiated.

Comment: @RomanC added stack trace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6005564/1654265

Comment: @AndreaLigios  Is it database problem

Comment: @AndreaLigios done steps given in post then also not working

Comment: Have you tried setting the reverse association (atom.setPage(page))?

Comment: @user3360944 you are correct I missed above statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace you posted is not the same that originated `IdentifierGenerationException`. The stacktrace posted means that someone is locking a database table to which your transaction wants to write.

If this is a development database, most probably it's a SQL GUI client like My SQL workbench that has a transaction opened that is not yet committed. It can also a process that you thought you killed that is still around.

To troubleshoot this, kill all java processes and then with MySql workbench or equivalent, see if there are any processes connected to the database. If you have administrator rights in the database you also kill the sessions manually, this will release the locks.

For the `IdentifierGenerationException` problem, you need to do:

```
page.setAtom(atom);
atom.setPage(page);
```

The reason for this is that the foreign key generator in one-to-one relations takes they key from one entity and uses the same value as the key for the other entity, as one table primary key is also a foreign key to the other table.

In this case the property `atom.setPage()` was null, and hibernate was trying to copy the key from Page to Atom, but `atom.getPage()` was null, causing the error message you posted. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253573/why-am-i-getting-org-hibernate-id-identifiergenerationexception) and this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/).